# Sort foreach about content with distance

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I am developing an application with the Geotools package and I have one problem:

```
public function prodcercanos()
{
    $cercanos = User::with('municipio')->with('productos')->get();
    $coordA   = Geotools::coordinate([44.4578589, 2.2951061999999998]); 
    foreach ($cercanos as $p) {
        $coordB   = Geotools::coordinate([$p->municipio->latitud,$p->municipio->longitud]);
        $distance = Geotools::distance()->setFrom($coordA)->setTo($coordB);
        echo $p->id;
        echo "<p>";
        echo $distance->in('km')->haversine();
        echo "</p>";
    }       
}
```

This code returns the distance between points in the `foreach` but I need to sort the `foreach` with the distance and I don't know how could I make this.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the foreach loop, put it all in an array, and than go over the array.
You can use the distance as the key, and the HTML output as a value.
You can use [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) function on the array to sort it by key.

```
public function prodcercanos()
    {
        $cercanos = User::with('municipio')->with('productos')->get();
        $coordA   = Geotools::coordinate([44.4578589, 2.2951061999999998]); 
        $output = [];
        foreach ($cercanos as $p) {
            $coordB   = Geotools::coordinate([$p->municipio->latitud,$p->municipio->longitud]);
            $distance = Geotools::distance()->setFrom($coordA)->setTo($coordB);
            $dis = $distance->in('km')->haversine();
            $output[$dis] = $p->id . "<p>$dis</p>";
        }       
        ksort($output);
        foreach ($output as $line) {
            echo $line;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for explain the solution , If i would like to send more information to the view , not only the id how could I pass ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sort()` function in PHP.
Syntax to use: `sort(array,sortingtype);`

Use the following link for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_sort.asp